# Retain value if present and use index-match for blank cell

Tags: excel, indexing, match, vlookup

I have two tables with a common ID column.

Table 1 may have values already present in Column 2. I want to retain the values present in Table 1, but at the same time update the values looking at Table 2. If I use a simple INDEX MATCH it overwrites the old values. Any way to retain the old ones but also update with the new ones?

INDEX-MATCH that updates all values. Same problem with vlookup

```
=IFNA(INDEX(Sheet2!B:B,MATCH(Sheet1!A:A,Sheet2!A:A,0)),"")
```

Table 1

[image]

Table 2

[image]

Thanks for the help.

Comment: no, there is not a way with formula.  You will need to use vba

Comment: Thanks. I can do that with vba using a look to check if the cell is blank. Is there any other way?

Comment: You could potentially filter for blanks, and only insert the formula into blank cells.

Comment: I would use a worksheet change event to trigger the change.

Comment: rather than "overwriting the old values in table 1", why not create an extra column in table 1 that loads all the value in table 2. Then in column 3 combines both (using `concatenate`), then hides the initial 2 columns for printing/export.